# When should I declare a move constructor without noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

The standard doesn't enforce noexcept on move constructors. In what circumstances is it acceptable/neccesary for a move constructor to throw?

Comment: +1, but keep in mind that move is an optimization. In my opinion, r value references is one of the things people spend way too much time thinking about. The best move constructor you can write is none. A throwing move constructor is not a great choice, but if it's your only choice and your profiling shows it is an improvement over copy on a critical path, then It would be hard to make an argument against it.

Answer (score 6):

When you really have no choice. Most of the time your move constructor should be `noexcept`. And they are by default.

See this: http://www.codingstandard.com/rule/12-5-4-declare-noexcept-the-move-constructor-and-move-assignment-operator/

> It is especially important to use noexcept for types that are
>   intended to be used with the standard library containers. If the move
>   constructor for an element type in a container is not noexcept then
>   the container will use the copy constructor rather than the move
>   constructor.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the situation when I have no choice?

Comment: @Klaufir I would guess that if you had (let's say) a container that guarantees atomic-like behavior (it either moves all or doesn't move any) and your elements wouldn't be copyable (like handle, for instance) - so no plan B - then your element type wouldn't work.

Comment: @Klaufir No sorry, I don't have an example :(. Maybe more experienced ppl can come up with something.

Answer (score 4):

The golden rule here is: *It depends*.

Here is an example where it *might* make sense:

```
// A lock_guard template somewhere up here...

template<typename mutex_t>
class shared_lock_guard
{
    mutex_t *mtx_ptr;

public:

    shared_lock_guard(lock_guard<mutex_t> &&other) :
    mtx_ptr{other.mtx_ptr}
    {
        if(this->mtx_ptr){

            // this might throw a system_error
            // if the syscall fails or if the
            // lock state was corrupted.
            //
            this->mtx_ptr->shared_relock();
        }

        other.mtx_ptr = nullptr;
    }

    // rest of implementation, etc...
};
```